# How to read in a file and have its variable name automatically take on the file name?

Tags: r, variables, readlines

How can I use something like `readLines` to save the file as a character string in my environment with its own file name as the variable?

I tried something like the pseudocode below without success.

```
paste(filename) <- readLines(filename)
```

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: `fn <- filename` and then assign `fn` as you need it

Comment: you can use `file_listing <- list.files(path = "~/xxx/yyy/zzz/")` to get the contents of a folder as a character string.

I use this regularly to check the contents of a folder, parse the names and import the file with the latest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assign` function could be an alternative:

```
assign("filename", readLines("filename"))
```

if your filename starts with a character different from a to z (e.g. `.`, `_`), you can always call your variable circumscribed with `` symbols